# Programmatically redirect users to the default "access restricted"

Tags: 8

I would like to programmatically redirect my users to the default "access restricted" page. I know that I need a "RedirectResponse" object for a simple redirect, but how do I specify the default "access restricted" page here?

Comment: Usually, a "access restricted" page is produced by returning a 403 status code, not redirecting to another page. Did you try something like `return new Response('', Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);`

Answer (score 42):

You can throw an exception at any point in your code:

**403:**

```
throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException();
```

**404:**

```
throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException();
```

The exception is then caught by DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber and a subrequest for `/system/403` or `/system/404` is returned, which you can configure in the basic site settings if you don't want to display a generic "access denied" or "not found" page.

Other options depend on where the code is placed:

- Return a 403 or 404 response from a controller or a form
- Set a response in an event if you are in an event subscriber.

What you should never do is to send a response directly. This doesn't stop the code and produces two responses, one you've sent and one returned by the Drupal kernel. This will result in unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be the right way:

```
    $response = new RedirectResponse('/system/403');
    $event->setResponse($response);
```

Answer (score 4):

Build your redirect from the system's access denied route.

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('system.403');
$response = new RedirectResponse($url->toString());
```

This takes you to the Drupal standard access denied page. The route is defined in `system.routing.yml` in core.

The top answer will give you a broken looking browser based Access Denied, which may be what you're looking for. If you want your Drupal UI to show, use the above.

Answer (score 2):

From a page, you can use:

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse(\Drupal::url('your.module.route.name'));
```

like : http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/88/page-redirection-on-drupal-8

Or from a from submit:

```
$form_state->setRedirect('your.module.route.name');
```

Then configure access permission of 'your.module.route.name'

If you dont know how to configure access permision, check:
http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/66/create-a-custom-permission-drupal-8

Comment: I have tried 

        $response = new Response('', Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        $event->setResponse($response);

this shows only a white page to the user. That's too less information. I want to show the default "access denied" page from Drupal.