# How can I allow the current user to only see their own page?

Tags: 8, routes

I created a page in a custom module. I want only the current user to access this page on their behalf.

For example, I am using it with ID 51. If I go to :

```
/user/51/tasks
```

I can see this page.

If I go on :

```
/user/78/tasks
```

I must have an error 403 access denied.

How to do this ?

```
task_notify.user_page.tasks:
  path: '/user/{user}/tasks'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\task_notify\Controller\TaskNotifyUserController::Tasks'
    _title: 'Liste des tâches'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**UPDATE :**

My custom module is here :

https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3076032

I applied kiamlaluno's answer but I have the following error :

[image]

/task_notify/src/Controller/TaskNotifyUserController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\task_notify\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;

class TaskNotifyUserController extends ControllerBase {

  public function Tasks() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'task_notify_user_template',
    ];
  }

  public function taskAccess(UserInterface $user, AccountInterface $account) {
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($account->isAuthenticated() && $user->id() == $account->id())
      ->orIf(AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'administer users'))
      ->cachePerUser();
  }

}
```

Comment: You can achieve that by following the answer here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/280699/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I inject UserInterface into Access Control?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/280698/how-do-i-inject-userinterface-into-access-control)

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 3):

*_permission* only allows to give access to the route to the users who have that permission; it doesn't allow to give access basing on more complex conditions, as in the case of this question. As described in [Custom route access checking](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes/custom-route-access-checking), the route definition should be similar to the following one.

```yaml
task_notify.user_page.tasks:
  path: '/user/{user}/tasks'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\task_notify\Controller\TaskNotifyUserController::tasks'
    _title: 'Tasks list'
  requirements:
    _custom_access:  '\Drupal\task_notify\Controller\TaskNotifyUserController::taskAccess'
    user: \d+
```

The `TaskNotifyUserController` class would need to contain at least the following code (and other methods you need from that controller, including `tasks()`).

```
class TaskNotifyUserController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Checks access for the users task page.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\user\UserInterface $user
   *   The user being viewed.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   The account viewing the page.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultInterface
   *   The access result.
   */
  public function taskAccess(UserInterface $user, AccountInterface $account) {
  public function taskAccess(UserInterface $user) {
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($account->isAuthenticated() && $user()->id() == $account->id())
      ->cachePerUser();
  }

}
```

If then the access to the route should be allowed also to users with a specific permission (for example, the permission to administer users), the `taskAccess()` code would be similar to the following one.

```
  /**
   * Checks access for the users task page.
   *
  /**
   * Checks access for the tasks tab.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\user\UserInterface $user
   *   The user being viewed.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   The account viewing the page.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultInterface
   *   The access result.
   */
  public function taskAccess(UserInterface $user, AccountInterface $account) {
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($account->isAuthenticated() && $user->id() == $account->id())
      ->orIf(AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'administer users'))
      ->cachePerUser();
  }
```

Don't forget to import the class used from the controller, adding the following lines at the top of the controller file.

```
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;
```

If the controller class uses other classes from different namespaces, similar lines must be added for each class.

I took the code used from Drupal core for the Tracker module as example. The Tracker module shows its tracker page on /activity/{user} using a controller to render it. See [TrackerController.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21tracker%21src%21Controller%21TrackerController.php/8.9.x).

```
  /**
   * Checks access for the users recent content tracker page.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\user\UserInterface $user
   *   The user being viewed.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   The account viewing the page.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult
   *   The access result.
   */
  public function checkAccess(UserInterface $user, AccountInterface $account) {
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($account->isAuthenticated() && $user
      ->id() == $account->id())->cachePerUser();
  }
```

The custom access callback is defined in [tracker.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21tracker%21tracker.routing.yml/8.9.x).

```
tracker.users_recent_content:
  path: '/activity/{user}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\tracker\Controller\TrackerController::buildContent'
    _title: 'My recent content'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\tracker\Controller\TrackerController::checkAccess'
    user: \d+
```

Comment: Each time you use a class from a different namespace, you need to add a line similar to `use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;` on the top of that file.

Comment: You need to add them in the files where those classes/interfaces are used. Adding them to the *task_notify.module* file, while those classes/interfaces are used in the *TaskNotifyUserController.php* would cause the error message you saw.

Comment: https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3076032/-/blob/master/src/Controller/TaskNotifyUserController.php What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: I just saw that you have updated your answer, thank you but there is an error `RuntimeException: Callable "Drupal\task_notify\Controller\TaskNotifyUserController::taskAccess" requires a value for the "$user" argument. in Drupal\Component\Utility\ArgumentsResolver->handleUnresolvedArgument() (line 142 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/ArgumentsResolver.php).`

Comment: I rewrote the code basing on the code Drupal core is using on one of its modules.

Comment: It does not work because I have a blank page with the error of the previous comment

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I applied the answer but I have an error. I have updated my question `RuntimeException: Callable "Drupal\task_notify\Controller\TaskNotifyUserController::taskAccess" requires a value for the "$user" argument. in Drupal\Component\Utility\ArgumentsResolver->handleUnresolvedArgument() (line 142 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/ArgumentsResolver.php).`

Answer (score 0):

In `TaskNotifyUserController::Task` you can access the current user with `Drupal::currentUser()`. Then compare that id with the id from the current `Request`, or if you're dealing with a node, the node's author's id (`uid`). If they don't match, issue a `RedirectResponse` or regular `Response('', Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN)`.

Comment: The [answer from @kiamlaluno](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294991/how-can-i-allow-the-current-user-to-only-see-their-own-page/294999#294999) is the better solution, because access checks in routes can do other things like control the visibility of menu items which your code in a controller can't. However, if you need to deny access from the inside of a controller then throw AccessDeniedHttpException, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215627/programmatically-redirect-users-to-the-default-access-restricted/215633#215633

Comment: Thanks! Good to know

Comment: I have updated my question